# Execute a animation before route/view-change in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-animations

I have a question how I can:

- Execute a animation before route/view-change in Angular.
- When a route/view change button is clicked - then a alert popup will show for a couple of seconds before the route/view-change is made.

I'm new to Angular and Typescript so please be gentle and tell me if you need any clarification.

Thanks beforehand!

Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to realize this would be to use the feature `(@animation.done)` of Angular Animations, so that you could change the route once this animation has finished to execute. I made a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anim-before-route) in which, when you click on the button, a popup shows and ask if you do want to change the route. If so, the animation starts running and once it's done, the page changes.

Here is how I did :

**component.ts**

```
export class PersonComponent {
  state = 'left';
  changeRoute = false;

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  goTo() {
    if (this.changeRoute) {
      this.router.navigate(['hello']);
    }
  }

  confirm() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to go to hello page ?")) {
      this.changeRoute = true;
      this.runAnimation();
    }
  }

  runAnimation() {
    this.state = 'left';
    this.state = 'right';
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<h1>Person page</h1>
  <button (click)="confirm()">Go to Hello page</button>

<div class="bar bar-div"></div>
<div [@load]="state" (@load.done)="goTo()" class="loading-bar bar-div"></div>
```

Once the progress bar has finished, the page changes.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me. I had to do some minor changes but this got me on the "right" track! :) @Brice